# Would this proof by induction for the sequence of the product of odd numbers be correct? Is there something I can do better with it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction

I'm new to proofs by induction, and I was challenged by my teacher to learn this when I came up with a form to represent this sequence. Would this be correct?

$$1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$
$$\text{If $n=1$, then }1=\frac{(2\cdot1)!}{2^1\cdot1!}$$
$$1=1$$
$$\text{Suppose the proposition holds for $n=k$ so that }1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}$$
$$\text{We show that the proposition holds for $n=k+1$ holds, i.e. }1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2(k+1)-1)=\frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}$$
$$1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k+1)=1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k-1)\cdot(2k+1)=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}\cdot(2k+1)$$
$$=\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^kk!}=\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^kk!}\cdot\frac{(2k+2)}{(2k+2)}=\frac{(2k+2)!}{2^kk!(2k+2)}=\frac{(2k+2)!}{2^kk!\cdot2\cdot(k+1)}$$
$$=\frac{(2k+2)!}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=\frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}$$
If so, is there anything I could improve on it format-wise?

Answer (score 1):

"Assume $n=k$ holds" is a bit of an odd phrasing. It's rather "Suppose the proposition holds for $n=k$." Similarly, "Show that $n=k+1$ holds so that *blah*" is really "We show that the proposition holds for $n=k+1$, i.e. *blah*".

Otherwise it looks fine to me, except that of course you have omitted to prove a base case. You have provided no way to deduce the result for $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up about the base case, I had it written down but forgot to add it to the MathJax! Does it look proper now?

Comment: Yep, seems sane. As a matter of good practice, it's better to avoid the "thing1 = thing2 // thing3 = thing4" style, because the "=" is standing for different things in each sentence (the first time, it's "we want to show that LHS equals RHS"; the second time, it's "LHS does indeed equal RHS"). Use your words! Say something like "We want to show thing1=thing2. Indeed, this is precisely thing3=thing4, which is true." Save chains of equality for when they all definitely do hold.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good looking proof! The first thing I noticed though, is that you never explicity take care of the base case, i.e. when $n=1$. I know that in this case it is quite trivial, but you should at least mention that it is trivially true. Otherwise, you never knock the first domino over, to use an analogy.

For the inductive step, you could simply start with "assume this proposition is true for $n$". Then derive that the proposition is true for $n+1$, exactly the way you did, and that is sufficient to prove that $P(n)\rightarrow P(n+1)$.

Comment: Thank you! Also updated the base case situation!